# how compare records and select them in third column in same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, cakephp-3.x

Table Interest_log

```
    Id  user_id  user_id_interested     
------  -------  ------------------  
     3        2                   3   
     5        3                   2   
     6        6                   2   
     7        6                   3   
     8        7                   2    
     9        2                   6
```

I'm selecting those users where user_id_interested =2 
very simple
    select a.user_id ,a.user_id_interested 
    from interest_log a 
    where a.user_id =2;

when I select those users where user_id_interested = 2 and in new column I select those user_id who also liked back to the user who like him.

**Expecting result**

```
     Id  user_id  user_id_interested     bUser_id
------  -------  ------------------     ----------- 
     5        3                   2       null
     6        6                   2        2
     8        7                   2       null
```

This is about who like user 2 and 
In bUserId, first row and third row has null while second row has value 2 because user_id 2 also liked user_id 6 but user 2 didn't like user 3, 7 so there is null

I wrote this query

```
SELECT a.user_id ,a.user_id_interested , b.user_id AS bUserId
FROM interest_log a
LEFT OUTER JOIN interest_log b
ON a.user_id_interested = b.user_id
WHERE a.user_id_interested =2
AND b.user_id = a.user_id_interested
```

but it's giving following result

```
user_id  user_id_interested  bUserId  
-------  ------------------  ---------
      3                   2          2
      3                   2          2
      6                   2          2
      6                   2          2
```

any idea what join should be used here.
i'm really thankful if someone can tell what join should be used and how to write tat join it in cakephp 3 .

Comment: i think you haven't got any answers because your columns don't make sense. I really can't figure out what the interest_log really contains

Comment: column user_id and  user_id_interested contains information of users who like whom. if user "6" like user 2 then 6 will go under user_id and  2 will go under user_id_interested. but here in this question, I  need to figure out those user who like each other.

Comment: @e4c5 hope so,  you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining on a sub query:

```
SELECT a.user_id ,a.user_id_interested, b.bUserId
FROM interest_log a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.user_id_interested AS bUserId FROM interest_log a WHERE a.user_id = 2
) as b ON a.user_id = b.bUserId
WHERE a.user_id_interested = 2
```

The query is asking to find the users who are interested in user_id 2, it is then joining bUserId against a sub query which is asking to find only the users that user_id 2 is interested in. Every time there is a match you get a result, and every time there isn't you get NULL.

This will give you a table that is similar to what you wanted:

```
+---------+--------------------+----------+
| user_id | user_id_interested | bUserId |
+---------+--------------------+----------+
|       3 |                  2 | 3        |
|       6 |                  2 | 6        |
|       7 |                  2 | NULL     |
+---------+--------------------+----------+
```

To write this in Cakephp 3:

```
$id = 2;
$query = $this->InterestLog->find()
    ->select([
        'InterestLog.user_id',
        'InterestLog.user_id_interested',
        'b.bUserId'
    ])
    ->join([
        'b' => [
            'table' => '(SELECT InterestLog.user_id_interested as bUserId FROM interest_log InterestLog WHERE InterestLog.user_id = ' . $id . ')',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'InterestLog.user_id = b.bUserId'
        ]
    ])
    ->where([
        'InterestLog.user_id_interested' => $id
    ]);
```